# Get a single column comprised of several values

Tags: mysql

How do I get a column of items separated by commas in MySQL?

If I do `select * from (select 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) a;` it gives me 5 different columns, instead of a single column named `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is your number of rows (1-5) fixed?

Comment: You want the value to be a single string with comma-separated values?

Comment: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) is just an example. I want just a column of some values.

Answer (score 5):

This is a standard SQL approach. It doesn't use any proprietary features.

```
select 1 as n
union all
select 2
union all
select 3
union all
select 4
union all
select 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mike's solution is the better one for static ranges, but here is a MySQL specific solution in case you need the number of rows to be easier to adjust;

```sql
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row 
FROM 
  (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t2,
  (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t4,
  (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t8,
  (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) t16,
  (SELECT @row:=0) a
WHERE @row < 5
```

This will generate up to 16 rows by just adjusting the WHERE clause, and is easy to expand since one extra select will double the range.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/16814).